# How can I quickly check exactly how many columns my terminal has?

Tags: terminal, display

After window resizing, font size changes, etc., how can I easily and quickly check what is the current display width of my terminal?

Comment: `stty size` will report all the info you need which you can then parse, cut, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has been answered (and mis-answered) repeatedly.  But:

- [`tput cols`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html) provides information that the operating system can tell you about the width.
- the `COLUMNS` variable may be set by your shell, but (a) it is unreliable (set in certain shells) and has the drawback that if exported *will* interfere with full-screen applications.
- the [`resize`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html) program can tell you the size for special cases where the terminal cannot negotiate its window-size with the operating system.

Further reading: [`COLUMNS`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-COLUMNS) in the ncurses manual page.

Comment: "interfering" with applications (full-screen or not) is not a drawback of exporting COLUMNS or LINES.  It is a feature.  It's how you control output height and width.   e.g. `COLUMNS=80 dpkg -l '*apt*'`

Comment: I get bug reports, you don't.  Bye.

Comment: learn how to handle those vars correctly then.  ttfn.

Comment: @cas ... maybe you didn't know this but Thomas Dickey is actually one of the devs of (n)curses. I think he has a good idea of how to handle them. The `LINES` one is even worse. It totally messes up the terminal and you have to reset it. `clear` doesn't cut it. The programmer of the application has **ABSOLUTELY NO CONTROL** over people lying to it (obviously)! It won't see that fact. Which if you were a programmer who's played with curses you'd know that rather than telling a dev who knows more than you that he should just handle it better. You can't. It's out of the application's control!

Comment: @cas Oh and it's not even (just) full screen applications. The variables will mess with the terminal. It can be useful yes but if you use them you should expect problems. There's nothing the programmer can do about that except try and manage the users lying to it. That is not always with a good result. It happens AFTER the termination. How do you propose an application solve that problem? Those variables are problematic. In curses the variables are `LINES` and `COLS` or you can use `getmaxyx()`. But the user can lie to it. You can even tell it it's much bigger than the monitor. Can't help it.

Comment: I know who he is. I disagree with him that using COLUMNS=nn to control output width is always a bad thing.  curses apps are far from the only thing that can be run in a terminal or console - they're not even the majority, far from it. Most programs run in ttys are simple line-oriented tools, and that's where setting COLUMNS is most useful, e.g. when your terminal is 132 columns wide (or 200+) but you want 80 column wide output to paste into an email or something.  BTW, I have written curses-based apps several times in the past, haven't had any need to do so for many years.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your shell, the `COLUMNS` (and `LINES`) variables may be automatically set when the window size changes.  bash, zsh, ksh do. dash doesn't.  tcsh doesn't.

From `man bash`:

> COLUMNS
>        Used by the select compound command to  determine  the  terminal width  when  printing selection lists.  Automatically set if the
>   checkwinsize option is enabled or in an interactive  shell  upon
>   receipt of a SIGWINCH.

and

> LINES
>
> Used by the select compound  command  to  determine  the  column
>   length  for  printing selection lists.  Automatically set if the
>   checkwinsize option is enabled or in an interactive  shell  upon
>   receipt of a SIGWINCH.

I find the following alias useful:

```
$ alias ttystat='echo $(tty) $TERM ${COLUMNS}x$LINES'
$ ttystat
/dev/pts/2 xterm 192x51
```

Answer (score 0):

There is undoubtedly a shorter way, but the following doesn't use anything but POSIX specified utilities to give a quick interactive check:

```
printf '0123456789\n1234567890\n' | sed '1s/./&&&&&&&&&&/g;1s/^.//;2s/.*/&&&&&&&&&&/'
```

Run the command and read the digits that are at the far right in your display.  Read it as a two-digit number downward; that tells you how many columns you have.

Example output (shown as displayed) on a 72 column terminal:

```
$ printf '0123456789\n1234567890\n' | sed '1s/./&&&&&&&&&&/g;1s/^.//;2s/
.*/&&&&&&&&&&/'
000000000111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777
777777788888888889999999999
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012
3456789012345678901234567890
$
```

Comment: It doesn't scale up if my terminal is 200 characters wide.  `tput cols` is more generally useful.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, thanks; you're correct.  Generally if I come up with a hacky way to do something and am sure there must be a better way, I self-answer a question on U&L SE.  I think it's better than putting the odd attempt at a solution in the question itself, where future readers must stumble through it to get to the better way.  :)