# Detect if terminal chops or rewraps lines

Tags: terminal

From what I understand, the "traditional" behaviour of terminal emulators is to chop long lines when the window is made narrower, while some terminals rewrap their contents on resize.

Is it possible for a Bash script (or as a last resort, a C program) to detect which of the two behaviours the terminal uses?

Comment: Passively or actively? I don't think there's a terminfo setting for that, but it should be detectable by displaying stuff, causing a resize and reading back from the screen.

Comment: @Gilles: Augh! That sounds really messy. So chopping Vs. rewrapping is a built-in non-changeable design decision made by each terminal software developer?

Comment: Yes, wrapping isn't a traditional feature. And those two aren't the only possible behaviors, I think some terminals not only remember the content of “chopped” lines but actually do allow setting the cursor position wherever there has been output, even if the target column is larger than the current width.

Comment: @Gilles: This is interesting to know. Thanks! So if you have some terminal content like an ASCII GUI, it's sort of impossible to gracefully handle resizing of terminal width, because you have no way of telling what your terminal does with lines when you resize?

Answer (score -1):

Why not just set the behavior if you are using bash?

For example, there are a few options:

```
shopt -s checkwinsize
```

will tell bash to checkwinsize and act appropriately. The man page notes:

> If set, bash checks the window size after  each  command and,  if
>   necessary, updates the values of LINES and COLUMNS.

You can also check the number of columns and lines and then set them:

```
echo $COLUMNS; echo $LINES
```

If they are not what you want, you can set them:

```
COLUMNS=75;
LINES=20;
export COLUMNS LINES;
```

You can do all of that from within a bash script.

Comment: So you mean the terminal can be configured from the command line to either wrap lines or cut lines? I thought this was a built-in, non-changeable thing that varied for each terminal software. As per your suggestion, I tried `shopt -s checkwinsize` and `shopt -u checkwinsize`. My terminal wraps line in both cases. Further ideas?

Comment: @forthrin referencing this for detection: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281661/how-can-i-quickly-check-exactly-how-many-columns-my-terminal-has I am wondering, are you on a terminal in X windows (not sure that matters, but that is where I am testing). I get the feeling from your comment, you want to cut text off... see this page for an example: https://superuser.com/questions/188865/how-to-make-bash-not-to-wrap-output

Comment: I'm on macOS using the built-in Terminal, but I need a solution that works for any UNIX terminal. `tput rmam` makes the cursor return to the start of the same line of you type to the end of the line. However, if I **resize** the window horizontally, the lines are wrapping. It's **this** behaviour I'm interested in detecting (**or** setting, if setting it is even possible.)

Comment: @forthrin ahh. I do not have access to a mac to completely verify. That is now an interesting problem though.. I was under the impression shopt -s checkwinsize would take care of the terminal being resized... but in "Terminal" I am not sure if that works. I am assuming you need it to work in Mac "Terminal" also?

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question. `checkwinsize` doesn't give any information about the behavior of the terminal when it's resized. The last part is also wrong: setting `LINES` and `COLUMNS` will not influence the terminal in any way.

Comment: @Gilles So what do they do?

Comment: @Hashim `LINES` and `COLUMNS` work the other way round: they provide information about the terminal size to applications.